# Auto Refresh on Google Data Studio using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have connected a Data Studio report to our internal SQL data source and I've been searching for a way to auto refresh the report at certain intervals.

The only thing I found so far is the plugin called `Data Studio Auto Refresh`, which is not working.

Is there anyway to set up auto refresh on my Data Studio report using Google Apps Script?

***The datastudio report is being projected to a large monitor in our office that's why I am trying any ways to auto refresh the report.***

Answer (score 3):

So since the report is being projected to our office monitor, as a workaround I tried creating a script and placing it to the developer tool console that will auto refresh the report at a chosen interval.

```
function refreshCases(){
    $(".refreshIcon").click(); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        refreshCases();
    },60000) 
}
refreshCases();
```

Comment: Quite a noob question: how can I actually open developer tool console in Data Studio...?

Comment: While on view mode, you can right-click anywhere on the window and click inspect.

Comment: Oh, it's browser developer tool console here.. I thought there is some kind of special console for DataStudio (like GAS editor). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set data freshness for a data source when adding a new source.

> You must be an editor of the data source to change this setting.
>
> You can do this from within a report, or from the Data Sources home
> page.
>
> 1. At the top, click Data freshness.
> 2. Under "Check for fresh data," select a new refresh option, if available.
> 3. Click SET DATA FRESHNESS.

You can set a different period of refresh depending on the source.
Here is the link to google documentation:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no native / Apps Script based method to auto refresh an opened Data Studio report page.

You can vote for this feature at the [official feature request tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5492224?p=1&q=componentid:196095%20status:(open%20%7C%20new%20%7C%20assigned%20%7C%20accepted)%20votecount%3E0&s=vote_count:desc).

Comment: Is this still true? In any case, the link is obsolete.

Comment: @LWC It is still true - there is no native / Apps Script based method to auto refresh an opened Data Studio report page. Thanks for the heads up - updated the link.

Comment: Your link is now a general search for "componentid:196095 status:(open | new | assigned | accepted) votecount>0". Can you give a specific link for this feature request?

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can do it using Data Studio Auto Refresh, what you need to do is enable the plugin then refresh the Data Studio your working for the plugin to work. The interval depends on what interval you choose. I'm using the plugin and its working. :D

Comment: It is already enabled but as what I've mentioned on my post, it is still not working for me. It doesn't give me the option to choose the interval.